# Means of copying derived class attributes without dynamic casting

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, double-dispatch

I am trying to find an efficient way (using polymorphism) to copy specific attributes between two derived classes externally. I have a set of data classes that derive from a base class `DataClassA`. I want to operate on these data classes in a separate filter class that takes `DataClassA` references as input and output parameters. The filter will perform the necessary operations common to `DataClassA`, but I also want to propagate class-specific attributes from my input to output class. Consider:

```
class DataClassA
{
public:
    virtual void copyAttributes( DataClassA& copyFrom );
}

class DataClassB : public DataClassA
{
public:
    virtual void copyAttributes( DataClassA& copyFrom );
};

class DataFilter
{
    void run( DataClassA& input, DataClassB& output )
    {
        //do some calculations here
           ...
        //then copy over attributes
        output.copyAttributes( input );
    }
};
```

My problem is obviously that the `copyAttributes()` depends on needing to know the types of both the input and output derived classes (which need not necessarily be the same). However, the filter will only handle references to the base class `DataClassA`. My reflex is to simply institute a `dynamic_cast`, though I risk getting my hand slapped (and other possible negative consequences). If I did this, I would simply create a `copyAttributes` method for each derived class that called the `copyAttributes` of the parent class, and then use `dynamic_cast` to see if the `copyFrom` object is of the same type:

```
void DataClassB::copyAttributes( DataClassA& copyFrom )
{
    //copy attributes from parent class  
    DataClassA::copyAttributes( copyFrom );

    //test if the class being copied from is of type DataClassB
    DataClassB* copyPtr = dynamic_cast<DataClassB*>&copyFrom;
    if( copyPtr != NULL )
    {
        //copy DataClassB-specific attributes from copyFrom to this
        ...
    }
}
```

The most similar post I could find on the problem was here [Virtual functions and polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440285/virtual-functions-and-polymorphism). My primary questions are: 1) is my proposed use of dynamic_cast inappropriate?; and 2) if so, how might I implement this `copyAttributes` another way? There were references to using a visitor design pattern though I'm not sure how that would look.

This is kind of a simpler version of what the Visualization Toolkit (VTK) does in the sense that I'm using classes of filters that operate on a number of different data classes. Interestingly, they handle RTTI by including macros that include the string name of classes and parent classes that can be compared directly for correct downcasting of datatypes.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what you mean by "attributes" and how you are storing them.

Comment: Attributes are just a subset of values that are not affected by the operation of the filter. In my specific case, I am interested in using member variables that contain status flags for the data and actual devices.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want multi-dispatch (as that I have done here: https://ideone.com/8VxALs)
That require that the visitor knows each derived types.

An other approach is to use a `dynamic_cast` each time.

A simple double dispatch can be done as follow:

```
class DataClassA
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void copyAttributes(DataClassA& copyFrom) { copyFrom.copyAttributesToA(*this); }
    virtual void copyAttributesToA(DataClassA& copyTo) { /* Implementation to copy A -> A */ }
    virtual void copyAttributesToB(DataClassB& copyTo) { /* Implementation to copy A -> B */ }  
};

class DataClassB : public DataClassA
{
public:
    void copyAttributes(DataClassA& copyFrom) override { copyFrom.copyAttributesToB(*this); }
    void copyAttributesToA(DataClassA& copyTo) override { /* Implementation to copy B -> A */ }
    void copyAttributesToB(DataClassB& copyTo) override { /* Implementation to copy B -> B */ }
};
```